# How to Force Uninstall of App on Hololens 2

Tags: hololens

I'm iterating on an app and have deployed/redeployed via Visual Studio, in addition to playing around with an appxbundle of the app.  Somehow I've gotten into a state where my app does not show up in the user interface, however the app still shows as installed in the device portal.

When I attempt to uninstall via the app portal, I am confronted with a rather generic error "Failed to uninstall package ".  I cannot deploy/debug via Visual Studio.  When I attempt to deploy/debug via VS, I get an error "RemoteCommandException: Another user has already installed a packaged version of this app. An unpackaged version cannot replace this.".

My question is, is there a way to "force" uninstall, or another method to clean up the uninstall, or discover the reason the app uninstall fails via the device portal?  I don't want to wipe the device if it's possible to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sharing the HoloLens with multiple people, so have multiple accounts in it? When they use their own Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) accounts, multiple users can each keep their own user settings and user data on the device.

And according to the error message you got,  this issue happens because the other user installed the same package in your HoloLens, you need to log in as the user who did it and uninstall it from that context. If you don’t know how to check the list of the users signed in your device, please go to Settings > Accounts > Other users, more information please see:[Share your HoloLens with multiple people](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-multiple-users)

Comment: In this case, no, I'm the only user installing anything.  All installs have been done using the device portal, or Visual Studio via deployment during debugging.  Mainly, I'm asking how I might troubleshoot an uninstall failure as it's clear the deployment is failing due to the previous version existing on the device.

Comment: I spoke to a HoloLens software engineer.  He asked if you could file feedback from your HoloLens device as close to your most recent uninstall attempt.  If you file feedback he can take a look at it.  I would suggest providing a descriptive title so we can link it to you.